# Why does jQuery mask say it's not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mask

When trying to use the jQuery `mask()` function, I get the following error in the console:

```
TypeError: $(...).mask is not a function
```

This is a sample of my code where this is happening:

```
<html>
<body>
<input type='text' id='phone' />
</body>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
//alert($);
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#phone").mask("(99) 9999-9999");
});
</script>

</html>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: make sure that you have included the plugin script on your page

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Jquery mask is a plugin. 
You can directly add this line in your HTML if you want to use a CDN version:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js"></script>
```

Another way is to use a package manager like npm or bower. To accomplish that, follow the instructions in the [README.md](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin) file of the project.

Comment: Thanks. I throught this was built-in in the jquery.

Comment: You should not use the link to a JavaScript in a gihub format. You should  use its minimized version publicly available or store it in a local file.

Comment: If I use mask "(99) 9999?9-9999" and type `123456789` I get the literally the `?` symbol: `(12) 3456?7-89`. How fix it?

Comment: @Sigismundus: It was for testing only. Since it worked, I download it to a local file.

Comment: OK - if you do not need ? character then you can remove it.

Comment: Yes you have to do the minifying process on your own server here. I'm sorry but I never used this plugin so I just can give you the link to some documentation: http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: @Sigismundus: I suposed it's for make the number optional.

Comment: It seems you must use `#` instead of `?`.

Comment: You could use [patterns](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) i.e. for numbers {pattern: /[0-9*]/}

Answer (score 22):

Change this line from

$(document).ready(function(){

to

$(document).ready(function($){

Comment: You absolutely do need the plug-in on the page, but if that still doesn't help you - do this!

Comment: :o that was it! What's the explanation? I already had the plugin on the page

Comment: Man, i already had the pkugin on page, but it wasn't working. This solved the problem. What is the explanation of this?

Comment: yeah.. what's the explanation?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery itself does not provide functionality for masking an input. You can use one of the [plugins](http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-mask-input-plugin/) avaiable for it.