# Bootstrap tooltip is not a function, Popper not working

Tags: javascript, webpack, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use separate modules of bootstrap in my website instead of include the whole minified file. But I'm freaking out, why is that so complicated? Or I'm complicating this?

```
"devDependencies": {
  "exports-loader": "1.1.1",
  "webpack": "4.39.2",
  "uglify-js": "3.6.0",
},
"dependencies": {
  "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
  "jquery": "3.4.1",
  "popper.js": "1.14.7",
 }
```

custom bootstrap.js in /js

```
/* Tries:
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'popper.js';
import 'popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js';
import 'popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'; */

window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
global.$ = $;


/* BOOTSTRAP CUSTOM IMPORTS */
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/util';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/alert';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/button';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/collapse';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/modal';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/popover';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/tab';
```

With that, my code compile with success but on chrome console this error appear

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
```

If I include this on my webpack.config.js:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
  'window.jQuery': 'jquery/src/jquery',
  Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
}),
```

The tooltip error is gone, but starts to do error on other libs, like:

```
//Error on chrome console
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mask is not a function
```

My Loading order of JS is:

```
LIBS (A WEBPACK MERGED FILE WITH ALL OTHER LIBS, LIKE JQUERY, MASKS, SLICK...)
BOOTSTRAP
POLYFILL
```

Searching the internet I see that a lot of people are experiencing this problem but the solutions they present are not working for me.

Please, anybody can help me?

Comment: have you tried this for your mask error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28512909/why-does-jquery-mask-say-its-not-a-function

Comment: Recheck your imports, jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS, call the tooltip function after the document is ready

Comment: @HemantMalik thanks, but it does not solve, because it isn't a mask error. It only occurs when I changed the bootstrap loader from node_modules instead of inclusion of minified version directly

Comment: @AvishkaDambawinna I have already done. I even attached the order to the question. In part, this resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for responses.

I figured out what is going on, not really understanding why but, bootstrap imports with JQuery were causing conflicts in the use of jquery by plugins, so, I had to remove jquery imported from bootstrap file then include manually on another process of plugins file, like that:

```
/* BOOTSTRAP.js CUSTOM IMPORTS */
//removed jquery imports
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/util';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/alert';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/button';
...
```

webpack.config:

```
    //I had to maintain that provider
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
    }),
    new MergeIntoSingleFilePlugin({
      files: {
        "js/libs.base.js": [
          //included jquery min file on merge of plugins
          path.join(source, 'src/libs/jquery', 'jquery-3.4.1.min.js'),
          path.join(source, 'src/libs/jquery-mask', 'jquery.mask.min.js'),
          ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help.

```
  // TOOLTIP PLUGIN DEFINITION
  // =========================

  var old = $.fn.tooltip

  $.fn.tooltip = function (option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this   = $(this)
      var data    = $this.data('bs.tooltip')
      var options = typeof option == 'object' && option
      if (!data) $this.data('bs.tooltip', (data = new Tooltip(this, options)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
    })
```

Comment: Thanks  @Samlinuxgeek, it does not solve, because $.fn.tooltip is undefined. I have already figure out what is going on, is a webpack config.